Lua debug hook triggers different amount of call/returning events if error occurred during execution
I'm writing a lua script profiler in C, and I found the lua_sethook C API. I expected the hook to trigger balanced amounts of entering/leaving events, so I can mesure the time cost of every function.
But the truth is that the returning (or leaving) event may be lost when there is an error raised during execution.
The case can be summarized by the following codes:
file test_hook.lua:
function my_hook(event, line)
    local info = debug.getinfo(2)
    print(event .. ": " .. info.short_src .. "  " .. tostring(info.name) .. "  " .. tostring(info.currentline))
end
debug.sethook(my_hook, "cr")

function AAA()
    print(nil + 1)
end

function BBB()
    pcall(AAA)
end

function CCC()
    BBB()
end

CCC()


With lua test_hook.lua, the output looks like this:
return: [C]  sethook  -1
call: test_hook.lua  CCC  16
call: test_hook.lua  BBB  12
call: [C]  pcall  -1
call: test_hook.lua  nil  8
return: [C]  pcall  -1
return: test_hook.lua  BBB  13
return: test_hook.lua  CCC  17
return: test_hook.lua  nil  19
return: [C]  nil  -1

function AAA throws an error, and the 4th call event is no longer enclosed by a return event.
In lua's interactive mode, the problem is similar:
... copy/paste code above ...
> CCC()
call: stdin  nil  1
tail call: stdin  nil  2
call: stdin  BBB  2
call: [C]  pcall  -1
call: stdin  nil  2
return: [C]  pcall  -1
return: stdin  BBB  3
return: stdin  nil  3

The 4th call event is not enclosed again.
Because of this, I cannot know when a function ends if an error occurred (even if it was correctly handled by pcall/xpcall). Is there any other way to know it?  What is the correct way to deal with it? How did existing lua profilers solve it?
Thanks!

You not only have to worry about errors, but also about tail calls. The usual method is to use the func field returned by getinfo to build a call stack to trace calls. Unfortunately, this method cannot determine when the error occurred, and can only be corrected when the next return happens.
local call_stack = {}

function my_hook(event, line)
    local info = debug.getinfo(2, 'f')

    -- push "call" and "tail call" onto the stack
    if event == 'call' then
        table.insert(call_stack, {func = info.func, is_tail_call = false})
    elseif event == 'tail call' then
        table.insert(call_stack, {func = info.func, is_tail_call = true})

    elseif event == 'return' then
        local ci

        repeat
            -- pop the last call info from the stack
            ci = table.remove(call_stack)
            if ci and ci.func ~= info.func then
                -- The stack is unbalanced
                -- An error was occured in ci.func
            end
        until ci == nil or ci.func == info.func

        while ci and ci.is_tail_call do
            ci = table.remove(call_stack)
            -- If the popped call is a tail call
            -- this "ci" (the preceding call) is also returned here
        end
    end
end


I know the case of tail call, as it is clearly stated in the manual that LUA_HOOKTAILCALL will not have a corresponding return event, and it is possible and not difficult to be correctly handled. The case of error seems much more severe, and I feel uncertain about manually correcting stack from parent level because it is not semantically rigorous. Anyway, thanks to your answer, I know there is no other choice >.<
